# Golang ethclient.Client - how to make RPC calls?

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum

How to call RPC endpoints using `ethclient.Client` ( https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum )?

Some methods don't have wrappers, and, as far as i can see, calling it directly is impossible
e.g.

```golang
client, err := ethclient.Dial(url)

// ok
client.BalanceAt(...)

// incorrect code, trying to access private field `c *rpc.Client`
client.c.Call("debug_traceTransaction", ...)
```

The only way i can think of is spinning up totally separate rpc client and keep both running at all times.
Is this the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ethclient.Dial` function (which you mentioned) uses the [rpc.DialContext](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.11/rpc#DialContext) function underneath, and the package also provides an [ethclient.NewClient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum@v1.10.11/ethclient#NewClient) function to create a new `ethclient.Client` with an existing rpc connection.

A possible solution could be to create a new rpc connection, then pass it to the `ethclient.Client`, so you're using one connection, but can use the RPC connection itself and the eth client as well.

Something like this:

```golang
rpcClient, err := rpc.DialContext(ctx, url)

ethClient := ethclient.NewClient(rpcClient)

// use the ethClient
ethClient.BalanceAt(...)

// access to rpc client
rpcClient.Call(...)
```